# unable to iterate res on subscribe a function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am trying to achieve get a document by given id from firebase and display it using angular.
I am geting response json object [object, object]
I am expecting iteratable array objects
.In this context all the related code is given blow
class.ts

```
      items: Product;
    ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) =>{
      if(paramMap.has('itemId')){
        this.id = paramMap.get("itemId");
// taking id from route
            this.itemService.getItem(this.id).subscribe(action =>{
              const data = action.payload.data();
               //i tried this.items = action; but it show error 
              console.log(data);
            })
          }
      });
    }
```

service.ts

```
getItem(itemId: string){
       return this.afs.doc(`products/${itemId}`).snapshotChanges();
     }
```

product.html

```
    <div *ngFor = 'let item of items' class = "row ">
 <div class="col-11">
            <h2 class="mb-2">{{item.name}}</h2>
            <p class="mb-2" >Specification: {{item.specification}}</p>
            <p class="mb-2">Description: {{item.description}}</p>
            <p class="mb-2">{{item.price}}</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` print ? pls put the response as well.

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.items = data` ?

Comment: if `this.items = action` shows an error, then it might just be that the type of action is not equal to `Product`. Also are you sure that `items: Product` shouldn't be a collection of Products as such `items: Product[]`?

Comment: Yes you are right Ruben but I want array of objects in this.item.while on subscribe(action =>{const data = action.payload.data();})

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `data.forEach(dt=> console.log(dt))`. If that is not possible, then you're simply not returning an array of objects but just an object.

However, you can check what that object is by simply looking at the result of `console.log(action)` within the `subscribe` and see where your collection is.

**Extra (specific to your case)**

Another useful tip is that you cannot return types of methods by adding `: returntype` after the parameter list, as such:

`main(string[] args): void { ... }`

This will help you and people that work on the project understand more about the functionality of the code and it will aswell show people on StackOverflow more intell into what classes/libraries you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for notice  I am actually want this.items = action; and after that I can iterate it in html